# Get substring into a new column

Tags: substring, kdb, q-lang

I have a table that contains a column that has data in the following format - lets call the column "title" and the table "s"

title

```
ab.123
ab.321 
cde.456
cde.654
fghi.789
fghi.987
```

I am trying to get a unique list of the characters that come before the "." so that i end up with this:

```
ab
cde
fghi
```

I have tried selecting the initial column into a table then trying to do an update to create a new column that is the position of the dot using "ss".

something like this:

```
t: select title from s
update thedot: (title ss `.)[0] from t
```

i was then going to try and do a 3rd column that would be "N" number of characters from "title" where N is the value stored in "thedot" column.

All i get when i try the update is a "type" error.

Any ideas? I am very new to kdb so no doubt doing something simple in a very silly way.

Answer (score 6):

the reason why you get the type error is because `ss` only works on string type, not symbol. Plus `ss` is not vector based function so you need to combine it with each `'`.

```
q)update thedot:string[title] ss' "." from t
title    thedot
---------------
ab.123   2
ab.321   2
cde.456  3
cde.654  3
fghi.789 4
```

There are a few ways to solve your problem:

```
q)select distinct(`$"." vs' string title)[;0] from t
x
----
ab
cde
fghi
q)select distinct(` vs' title)[;0] from t
x
----
ab
cde
fghi
```

You can read here for more info: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/casting/#vs

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to make use of the [`0:`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#load-csv) operator, to parse around the "." delimiter. This operator is especially useful if you have a fixed number of 'columns' like in a csv file. In this case where there is a fixed number of columns and we only want the first, a list of distinct characters before the "." can be returned with:

```
exec distinct raze("S ";".")0:string title from t
`ab`cde`fghi
```

OR:

```
distinct raze("S ";".")0:string t`title
`ab`cde`fghi
```

Where `"S "` defines the types of each column and `"."` is the record delimiter. For records with differing number of columns it would be better to use the `vs` operator.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of WooiKent's answer using `each-right` (`/:`) :

```
q)exec distinct (` vs/:x)[;0] from t
`ab`cde`fghi
```